# Dropdown List autofill to last row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm new in VBA macro. Well I've already figured some of it's code but I have a difficulties for this one.

I want to add a dropdown list on cell ("F10") and I also want to add a vlookup formula on ("G10"). Once the user choose any value from dropdown list which is on cell ("F10") there will be a corresponding value in cell ("G10")

now I want the dropdown list will autofill until the very last row of the data or used cells, same with vlookup
I have this code but it has an error and I don't know what to do..

```
ActiveCell.Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "Sample, Partner, Single, Joint"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-1],[Macro.xlsm]Sheet2!R2C1:R21C2,2,FALSE), "" "")"
ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.Range("G:G").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(3, -1).Range("G:G").Select
```

since my macro is creating a new workbook and save it depends on it's branch name for the filename. so I hard code the value for the dropdown list.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are looking up with the formula adjacent to your column F validation, but your formula needs to be changed to vlookup a cell not a column range.

After the formula is inserted what are you trying to do?

```
    ActiveCell.Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "Sample, Partner, Single, Joint"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!R2C1:R21C2,2,FALSE), "" "")"
```

Comment: oh sorry, I don't know how to explain or ask for it. I'm not good in English lol. but anyway thank you for your response. I've already got it. I just input the data on the blank columns after validating it the column is hidden :D

Comment: What was the answer to your solution then?

Comment: I've just hard code the choices into a blank column then hide that column. :)